# Redis GET returns short write error in Go

Tags: go, redis

I have some code to schedule jobs across processes on a given frequency:

```
func doMasterInner(ctx context.Context, conn redis.Conn, suffix string, 
    freq time.Duration, op func(context.Contex) error) error {

    key := fmt.Sprintf("myserviced_%s", suffix)
    _, err := redis.Int(conn.Do("GET", key))

    var shouldRun bool
    if err != nil {
        if err != redis.ErrNil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to get %s from Redis, error: %v", key, err)
        }

        shouldRun = true
        if _, err := conn.Do("SETEX", key, int(freq.Seconds()), 0); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to set timer for %s in Redis, error: %v", key, err)
        }
    }

    if shouldRun {
        return op(ctx)
    }

    return nil
}
```

However, when I call this code:

```
pool := &redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle:     3,
    MaxActive:   4,
    Wait:        true,
    IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
    Dial:        func() (redis.Conn, error) { 
        return redis.Dial("tcp", addr, 
            redis.DialPassword(password),
            redis.DialConnectTimeout(5 * time.Second)) 
    },
}

conn := pool.Get()
defer conn.Close()

err := doMasterInner(context.Background(), conn, "assets", time.Hour, 
    func(ctx context.Context) error {
        // do something here
        return nil
    })

fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
```

The print function prints `Failed to get myserviced_assets from Redis, error: short write`. I'm not sure why this is happening as this error message indicates that it is the `GET` that is failing. What causes Redis to return a `short write` message on a GET?

Comment: The error is reported by [bufio](https://godoc.org/bufio), not by the Redis server. This looks like a data race to me.  Run the application with [the race detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) to find potential problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this code in and of itself wasn't the issue. The real issue was that I was using this code and calling many instances of `doMasterInner` concurrently with the same `redis.Conn` object. Although I'm not exactly sure what caused this issue, my guess is that having multiple threads attempting to write to the same `redis.Conn` buffer caused the error. Modifying `doMasterInner` like this fixed the issue:

```
func doMasterInner(ctx context.Context, conn *redis.Pool, suffix string, 
    freq time.Duration, op func(context.Contex) error) error {

    conn := pool.Get()
    defer conn.Close()

    key := fmt.Sprintf("myserviced_%s", suffix)
    _, err := redis.Int(conn.Do("GET", key))

    var shouldRun bool
    if err != nil {
        if err != redis.ErrNil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to get %s from Redis, error: %v", key, err)
        }

        shouldRun = true
        if _, err := conn.Do("SETEX", key, int(freq.Seconds()), 0); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Failed to set timer for %s in Redis, error: %v", key, err)
        }
    }

    if shouldRun {
        return op(ctx)
    }

    return nil
}
```